# I want to know about join query for my question

Tags: php, sql

I had two tables containing 
Income day book :

```
SELECT `id`, `type`, `cause`, `from_income`, `amount`, `remarks`, `date`
FROM `income_daybook`
```

Expense day book :

```
SELECT `id`, `type`, `cause`, `to_expense`, `amount`, `remarks`,  `date`
FROM `expense_daybook`
```

I want to get both tables , using the date filter i want to see both data in the particular data ,the date filter is taken by the date in the table

Comment: Not sure it's a JOIN that you want. How are these tables related?

Comment: Can you show table structure and sample data and the expected result

Comment: are you sure it's not a UNION query you need, instead of JOIN? Or just two queries separately? As others have said, show us sample data and expected output, then we can be clear. Also what have you tried so far? This is not a free write-my-code, do-my-research or even do-my-thinking service. We'd like to _help_ you solve your problem, not just do it all for you. From what you've posted here, it looks like you haven't even begun to consider this before posting here. What actual issue are you facing, specifically?

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to stich the resultsets of the 2 queries together.
Provided that the unioned fields have the same data types.

```
SELECT id, `type`, cause, from_income, amount, remarks, `date`
FROM income_daybook
WHERE `date` >= CAST('2018-12-01' AS DATE)

UNION ALL

SELECT id, `type`, cause, from_income, amount, remarks, `date`
FROM expense_daybook
WHERE `date` >= CAST('2018-12-01' AS DATE)

ORDER BY id, `type`
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` applies to the combined result.
And that the result will use the field or alias names of the top query.